# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I am a JavaScript newbie, I am trying to build a simple countdown timer that counts down only in seconds. It is showing uncaught type error for x. Which what I think means that the function is not recursing. The code is as below:

```
function timer(x, elem){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elem);
    elem.innerHTML = x;
    if (x > 0) {
        setTimeout(timer(x-1, elem),1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, think it through. What is `elem` the *second* time you pass it into the function?

Comment: The issue is in your HTML.

Comment: do you have DOM node in elem or the string with ID of this DOM node?

Comment: @Praveen Maybe, but there's a more obvious problem... two in fact.

Comment: @deceze I know... And I am def sure, this OP won't come back in 5 mins.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think the downvotes are unkind here. This seems to a reasonable error by a newbie, and enough context is clearly provided for us to see the error. @randeep-gill, the main problem, as deceze pointed out in the first comment, is that you are overwriting the value of the variable `elem` to be a DOM element, and then trying to re-use it as if it were still a string. Try using two different variables. In general, a useful tool is the `debugger` statement. If you read up on how to use that, you can go through the code line by line and see if everything is what you expect it to be each time.

Comment: @SamFen "Enough Context", so solve it?

Comment: elem remains the same.

Comment: @RandeepGill Why not just share the HTML and full code, so that the issue is clear and you get a solution?

Comment: The issue is not witht the HTML it is diplaying the value where it should

Comment: @RandeepGill **1.** Show your HTML. **2.** Showing uncaught type error for x. Show us the full error.

Comment: @SamFen: We know of an error in the recursive call but not in the initial call, and the OP seems reluctant to share much more information.

Comment: @RandeepGill: When you say *"elem remains the same"*, what does that mean? Is your initial call passing a DOM element? If so, why are you passing a DOM element to `.getElementById()`? That method takes a string, and if you already have the element, there's clearly no need to fetch it.

Comment: @praveen-kumar: Ok, solved below.

Comment: @squint what do you want to know. its a very simple code everythings just too obvious. you can copy the code and run it on your own browser.

Comment: @RandeepGill You've got an answer.

Comment: @RandeepGill: I already told you. For a beginner, you sure seem to think you know it all.

Comment: @squint there is no probs with the elem. the problem Ive tried to build a recursive function which passes value only the first time. ok I will try without the dom elem

Comment: @RandeepGill: So your initial call passes an element and not a string? That's what we don't know.

Comment: @RandeepGill Did my answer below help you at all? It ran fine for me, and seemed very close to what you were already doing.

Comment: @SamFen your solution was brilliant  ran fine here and I tried to run it on my system as well.. however for some reason it showed the same error as it did before i.e it returned null value for x on recursion...However thanks your solution cleared some important concepts for and I did want to mark it as correct..Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

1. You are overwriting the value of `elem` to be a DOM element, and then trying to reuse it as if it were still a string
2. `setTimeout` expects a function that it can call every 1000 ms. Instead you are calling a function and passing the result to `setTimeout`. The distinction is a little confusing, but it may help to see it separated out into another variable:

This is what you are currently doing

```
var myFuncResult = timer(x-1, elem);   // this returns the result of the function
setTimeOut(myFuncResult, 1000);
```

Instead you want

```
var myFunc = function() { timer(x-1, elem) }; // this returns a function that can be called
setTimeOut(myFunc, 1000);
```

Of course you can put the function directly into `setTimeout`, like you attempted to do.

The following does what you want (Hit "Run"):

```js
function timer(x, elem){
    var DOMelem = document.getElementById(elem);
    DOMelem.innerHTML = x;
    if (x > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          timer(x-1, elem)
        },1000);
    }
}

timer(10, "my-timer");
```

```html
<div id="my-timer"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the OP is passing a string, and not an element in the initial call?

Comment: Of course I don't know, but it certainly seems like the intent. That seems confirmed by OP saying "the problem Ive tried to build a recursive function which passes value only the first time." If it worked the first time, which is what is implied, then it roughly fits with the facts: the function works correctly once, and then he gets a type error the second time. OP is confused about what's wrong, of course, but only as much as a beginner is expected to be.

Comment: OP says it passes value only the first time, not that it "works". OP also said *"I will try without the dom elem"*. OP also said *"I think means that the function is not recursing"*. The question is incomplete, which is why we downvote it, which has nothing to do with kindness.

Comment: "passes value only the first time": it shows up on his screen the first time. "I think means that the function is not recursing": the function is not being called the second time, in this case because setTimeout was being used incorrectly. Think like a beginner. Do you think that the solution I offered is a reasonable interpretation of what OP was trying to do or not?

Comment: That's all conjecture. You don't know if it's printing to the screen. He's a JS beginner, yet knows concepts like recursion. The second call to the function would be the first recursive call, which would fail if `elem` is a DOM element on the first call. I think your answer has about a 50/50 chance of being what the OP was trying to do, which is why we ask for more information instead of answering incomplete questions. Yet the OP has consistently resisted providing actual info. Can't imagine why anyone would give the question +1. It's a disservice to how the site works.